# How to capture a window screen shot in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Whenever I want to capture a screenshot in my code I was using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PRTSCR</kbd>, but it is not working.
**Is there anther way to capture a screenshot pragmatically in Ruby?**

Here's is my code: `require 'win32ole'`

```
autoIt = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
autoIt.Send("{CTRLDOWN}{PRINTSCREEN}{CRTLUP}")
```

Comment: AutoIt has vast scope in ruby + Windows automation, looks like you are trying to reproduce general window way of capturing the foreground solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we have a library for screenshot in win32 we can make use of that library in order to solve this problem.
Here is the piece of code that might help you

```
require 'win32/screenshot'
Win32::Screenshot::Take.of(:foreground).write("Screenshot.png")
```